What does the percentage mean when I catch an animal?
Whenever I catch and release an animal at the home base, there is a percentage next to the message about me catching the animal. What does this percentage mean?


According to the Fandom,

The percentage by this message is determined by how many you have caught over the year (it resets every winter), and determines that species' effectiveness at dealing with pests. Frogs, spiders and snails all prevent different types of pests, so take care. You can observe them from the status screen after talking to Tauemon about the rice.

The higher the percentage, the better.

The status bars on Snail, Spider and Frog are all better when higher, as they indicate their effectiveness in removing pests, which are the rest of the fauna - it's better when they're lower

(that is, it's better when the fauna bars are lower)

, as higher pest values can leave your crops susceptible to disease. Note that you can also see the status of the weeds here,

(I assume 'here' means the status screen)

which also determines how susceptible your rice is to weeds-derived diseases. You can't get the percentage values to 100% no matter how hard you try however - usually around 40% is good, though.

The fandom also mentions that pulling weeds can deter pests, and that if you keep ducks out, they will eat spiders, which lowers the spider's effectiveness at dealing with pests.
